# why doesn't the html table give me p-values and add -9 values? table1

Tags: r, p-value, chi-squared, t-test

[image]I'm trying to make a table with several nominal values and a few logical values against a single nominal value using the "table1" package. I also want each column to include a p value.

This code: `table1(~ age + obese + low_income + married + HSless + hosp_visits_2years + ER_2years + nights_hosp_2years | has_PCP, data=Oak, droplevels=F, render=rndr, render.strat=rndr.strat, overall=F)`

Gives me this warning:

> Warning message:
>   In table1.formula(~age + obese + low_income + married + HSless +  :
>   Terms to the right of '|' in formula 'x' define table columns and are
>   expected to be factors with meaningful labels.

The output also gives -9 as a value for the has_PCP nominal values, which I don't want either.

Here is where I got the code from (column of p values).
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

Comment: is `has_PCP` a factor with meaningful labels?

Comment: It has 1 and 0. -9 is a value too (-9 means missing), but I don't want that included.

Comment: So take a subset of the data that includes only 0 and 1 for `has_PCP`.

Comment: I get a second error when I use subsets, and the p-value column still doesn't show up.

Comment: Hard to help without your data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding p-values using the `table1` function from the package of the same name is a hack that doesn't seem to work based on code in the vignette you linked to.

For an alternative, try the `tableStack` function from the epiDisplay package.

```
library(epiDisplay)  # for the function
library(MatchIt)     # for the lalonde data

data(lalonde)

labs <- c("No","Yes")
lalonde <- within(lalonde, {
                  treat    <- factor(treat, labels=c("Control", "Treatment"))
                  black    <- factor(black, labels=labs)
                  married  <- factor(married, labels=labs)
                  nodegree <- factor(nodegree, labels=labs)
})

attr(lalonde, "var.labels") <- c("Treatment","Age (yrs)","Education","Black","Hispanic","Married", 
                             "No high school diploma", "1974 Income", "1975 Income", "1978 Income")
```

That's just preparing the variable and value labels.

The following command creates the table for a subset of the variables. You can view the output on the screen,

```
Table1 <- tableStack(vars=c(age, black, married, nodegree, re78), by=treat, dataFrame=lalonde, 
                     iqr=re78, name.test=FALSE)

Table1
```

or send it to a text file.

```
write.csv(Table1, file="Table1.csv")
```

Which you can open in Excel and then copy to Word with some minor formatting required.

[image]

The tests are automatically chosen based on the class of the variables specified in `vars`. Specifying variables in `iqr` forces the function to show medians with IQR for these variables and performs a ranksum test. All other numeric variables specified in `vars` will display means with SD and a t.test (with variances pooled) or ANOVA will be performed depending on the number of groups. A chi-squared or Fisher's test will be performed for factors. Unfortunately, the function fails if any variable has a zero count, which is true for many of your variables (obese, low income, married...). So it's not ideal for data exploration.

Comment: When I use this frame of code with my dataset, I get three different errors. I can post them if needed; they're long so I didn't do it here. Furthermore, I didn't have a problem recreating the table I wanted using the dataset that came with the vignette in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm too lost with this function; gonna try something else.